# Fazer insert do formato json em mysql e recuperar em Java

Tags: java, mysql, json

Tenho a seguinte String no formato **json**:

```
{
  "ADT":"0",
  "CHD":"0",
  "INF":"0"
}
```

Preciso fazer o **insert** em uma tabela no **banco mysql** e recuperar isso em **Java**.
Estou usando VARCHAR(50) e fica assim:

```
{
"ADT":"0",
"CHD":"0",
"INF":"0"
```

Vi que no Mysql tem o tipo de campo que se chama **Blob**, usado para binarios, mas não entendi como recuperar no **Java**.

Comment: Dependendo do tamanho, pode ser uma coluna varchar ou text mesmo.

Comment: OK, Obrigado vou tentar o text

Comment: Podes recuperar o Blob como um vetor de bytes.

Comment: O PostgreSQL tem uma grande variedade de tipos de colunas, incluindo XML e JSON. O MySQL, que eu saiba, é só text e blob mesmo.

Comment: Você pode colocar só a string em si e depois adicionar as chaves {} no java ou usar algum comando do tipo stringfy.

Answer (score 0):

Se o `JSON` tiver somente essas três propriedades, talvez seja melhor persistir como texto.
De qualquer forma, o Java possui um objeto para trabalhar com `Blob`:

#### Inserindo:

```
String jsonString = "{'ADT':'0','CHD':'0','INF':'0'}";

Blob blob = con.createBlob(); // 'con' = um objeto de conexão criado anteriormente
blob.setBytes(1, jsonString.getBytes());

PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foo VALUES(?)");
pstm.setBlob(1, blob);
```

#### Recuperando:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("data"); // 'rs' = algum ResultSet criado anteriormente
byte[] blobBytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
String jsonString = new String(blobBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Campos do tipo BLOB usamos para salvar arquivos como imagem, documentos, etc.
Se quer um campo grande de texto utilize o CLOB.

Cuidado com CLOB, pois é um campo muito pesado e pode te prejudicar em querys que tragam muitos registros dessa tabela. Já tive problemas com CLOB em cópias de banco de dados, em dumps, evita se puder.

Se for um JSON pequeno salva como texto mesmo! (Mysql é varchar? Não me lembro...)

Caso queira transformar o JSON em um objeto quando voltar com ele do banco de dados usa o GSON do Google.

Abraços